# Structs and Mappings

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

I am going through a tutorial at the moment and have just covered the basics of mappings and structs which I feel like I understand. However, in the next section of the tute we put together mappings and structs and I become a bit lost in the section I bolded ** **. Would someone be able to very slowly take me through the logic so I might be able to better understand what's happening?

````
        uint amount;
        uint timestamp;
    }

    struct Balance {
        uint totalBalance;
        uint numDeposits;
        mapping(uint => Transaction) deposits;
        uint numWithdrawals;
        mapping(uint => Transaction) withdrawals;
    }

    mapping(address => Balance) public balanceReceived;


    function getBalance(address _addr) public view returns(uint) {
        return balanceReceived[_addr].totalBalance;
    }

    function depositMoney() public payable {
        balanceReceived[msg.sender].totalBalance += msg.value;

        **Transaction memory deposit = Transaction(msg.value, block.timestamp);
        balanceReceived[msg.sender].deposits[balanceReceived[msg.sender].numDeposits] = deposit;**
        balanceReceived[msg.sender].numDeposits++;
    } ```
````

Answer (score 1):

That function can be refactored as follows:

```js
function depositMoney() public payable {
        balanceReceived[msg.sender].totalBalance += msg.value;

      // Creates an instace of `Transaction` struct with `amount` = msg.value and `timestamp` = block.timestamp.
      // A code liket his is also possible: `Transaction memory deposit = Transaction({amount: msg.value, timestamp: block.timestamp});`
      Transaction memory deposit = Transaction(msg.value, block.timestamp);
      
      // Get the Balance struct instance in the `balanceReceived` mapping under the `msg.sender` address.
      Balance storage balance = balanceReceived[msg.sender];

      // Assign the new `deposit` Transaction struct instance to this `balance.deposits` mapping.
      balance.deposits[balance.numDeposits] = deposit;

      // Increase the `numDeposits` so next time when we do `balance.deposits[balance.numDeposits] = deposit;` as the line of code above,
      // we set a new 'deposite' to a new `numDeposits`.
      balance.numDeposits++;

    }
```

The line of code like:

```js
Transaction memory deposit = Transaction(msg.value, block.timestamp);
```

is just creating a `Transaction` struct instance in memory with the `msg.value` and `block.timestamp`.
It could also be done more explicit like this:

```js
Transaction memory deposit = Transaction({amount: msg.value, timestamp: block.timestamp});
```

Line `balanceReceived[msg.sender].deposits[balanceReceived[msg.sender].numDeposits] = deposit;` is really doing a bunch of things that could be refactored to:

```js
// Get the Balance struct instance in the `balanceReceived` mapping under the `msg.sender` address.
Balance storage balance = balanceReceived[msg.sender];

// Assign the new `deposit` Transaction struct instance to this `balance.deposits` mapping.
balance.deposits[balance.numDeposits] = deposit;
```

As you can see, it simply gets the `Balance` struct instace of the `msg.sender` from the `balanceReceived` mapping to update it.

It assigns the new `Transaction deposit` instance to the `deposits` mapping inside the `Balance` struct instance, where the key is the value of `numDeposits`, which is a property that is increased everytime you add a new `deposit` so next time you can save another deposit in a difference 'index'.

And then finally it is increasing the `numDeposits` property:

```js
balance.numDeposits++;
```

That's it.